# Sitemap Generation Issue - URLBuilder - must be type of string - error

Tags: error, urlbuilder

I am trying to generate a sitemap.xml file in the Magento 2.3.5-p1 admin area, however I get a blank screen after clicking generate. I check the php logs and receive this error:

```
    AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Image\\UrlBuilder::getUrl() must be of the type string, null given, called
in /home/363882.cloudwaysapps.com/qzzbnfgmbr/public_html/vendor/mageworx/module-xmlsitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php on line 527 and
defined in /home/363882.cloudwaysapps.com/qzzbnfgmbr/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image/UrlBuilder.php:65\nStack trace:\n#0
/home/363882.cloudwaysapps.com/qzzbnfgmbr/public_html/vendor/mageworx/module-xmlsitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php(527):
Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Image\\UrlBuilder->getUrl(NULL, 'product_page_im...')\n#1
/home/363882.cloudwaysapps.com/qzzbnfgmbr/public_html/vendor/mageworx/module-xmlsitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php(480):
MageWorx\\XmlSitemap\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Catalog\\Product->getProductImageUrl(NULL)\n#2
/home/363882.cloudwaysapps.com/qzzbnfgmbr/public_html/vendor/mageworx/module-xmlsitemap/Model/ResourceModel/C...\n', referer:
```

I have checked sys.log and exception.log with no additional information. Has anyone come across this before? This is the first time I have tried to generate a sitemap. I have also disabled the mageworx module and it still produces the same result. I migrated from M1.6.2, so I think there may have been something not quite right with one or more images in the DB that would cause this. Any tips, suggestions etc... would be great appreciated. Thank you very much for anyone's time.

Comment: Looks like you are using a third party extension to build sitemap? Have you raised it with the devs?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have since disabled the third party module completely and the result is the exact same with default magento sitemap. I then disabled include images in sitemap and it would generate. It definitely has something to do with the image URLBuilder. I'm guessing there is something in the database dealing with the images that may be causing the issue. I do not know how to further troubleshoot because none of the logs include additional information about this. EDIT: Mageworx says it is my problem and is not willing to help. That's pretty fair, but I'm hoping they can show right direction